# Naive implementation of exponential function

Tags: haskell, types

I am trying to do a naive implementation of the exponential function as follows:

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}

fact :: (Integral a) => a -> a
fact n = foldr (*) 1 [n,(n-1)..1]

-- Sum of x^i / i! over i, from i=0 to i=n
e' :: (Eq a, Integral a, Fractional a) => a -> a -> a
e' _ 0 = 1.0
e' x n = p / f + e' x (n-1)
    where
        !f = fact n
        !p = x^n
```

But haven't been able to make it work since I can't show the result on console because of this message related to `Show`:

```
<interactive>:108:1:
    No instance for (Show a0) arising from a use of 'print'
    The type variable 'a0' is ambiguous
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Show Double -- Defined in 'GHC.Float'
      instance Show Float -- Defined in 'GHC.Float'
      instance (Integral a, Show a) => Show (Ratio a)
        -- Defined in 'GHC.Real'
      ...plus 90 others
    In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
>
```

I know is something related to the type that `Show` is trying to display, so tried casting it but didn't work: `e' 1 15 :: Integer`

The type `(Eq a, Integral a, Fractional a) => a -> a -> a` was inferred by the compiler even though I initially wanted to use `(Eq a, Integral a, Fractional b) => a -> a -> b` without success.

The questions are:

**1. How can I make this code work? I don't understand how to solve `is ambiguous` problems correctly.**

**2. How can I use other type (maybe more appropriate if that is possible) than `(Eq a, Integral a, Fractional a) => a -> a -> a` ?**

Comment: There is no type which is simultaneously `Integral` and `Fractional`, so defaulting isn't working for you. You need apply `fromIntegral` to the integral values when you use them in fractional computations (such as `(/)`).

Comment: What is defaulting? Those classes where inferred by the compiler.

Comment: @OneEyeQuestion While the compiler may have inferred the both classes, that doesn't mean that there is a type that implements both.  Those type classes have nothing special about them, the compiler doesn't view them differently just because they're defined in `base`.  You could theoretically define a type that implemented both, but it probably wouldn't behave very well.  Instead, I would recommend using `fromIntegral` (as luqui has state) to coerce `Integral` values.

Comment: I tried `fromIntegral p / fromIntegral f`, but isn't working. As stated in the question, I think it is related to `Show` being unable to decide which type to display.

Comment: @OneEyeQuestion Try `e' :: (Eq a, Integral a, Fractional b) => a -> a -> b` along with `fromIntegral p / fromIntegral f`.  It works just fine for me.

Comment: That solved it. Could you please post an answer containing that and also, if possible, a more appropriate type; that is, an answer to the question #2 of the post?

Comment: With appropriate I mean a type that allows me to be more flexible, for example having rational exponents.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments there is no type that is both a member of `Integral` and `Fractional`. The type you failed to use is indeed the correct type, only that you needed to convert `f` and `p` from `Integral` with `fromIntegral`.

Here is your code with the appropriate modifications:

```
e :: (Eq a, Integral a, Fractional b) => a -> a -> b
e _ 0 = 1.0
e 1 _ = 1.0
e x n = p / f + e x (n-1)
    where
        !f = fromIntegral (fact n)
        !p = fromIntegral (x^n)
```